# Android - Fix image rotation with Exif

Tags: android

I'm using the code below to try to fix an image rotation problem. Look at the code:

```
public class ModuleActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    File imgFile;
    ImageView dnc_image = null;
    private BDSQLiteHelper bd;

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_module);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        final int id = intent.getIntExtra("ID",0);
        bd = new BDSQLiteHelper(this);
        final Module module = bd.getModule(id);
        final File imgFile = new  File(module.getImagem().toString());


        final ImageView dnc_image = (ImageView) 
        findViewById(R.id.profile_image);
        File imgFile = new  File(dnc.getImagem().toString());
        if(imgFile.exists()) {
            Bitmap myBitmap = BitmapFactory.decodeFile(dnc.getImagem());
            rotateImage(myBitmap);
            dnc_image.setImageBitmap(myBitmap);
        }

    private void rotateImage(Bitmap bitmap){

        ExifInterface exifInterface = null;

        try {
            exifInterface = new ExifInterface(imgFile.getAbsolutePath());
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        int orientation = exifInterface.getAttributeInt(ExifInterface.TAG_ORIENTATION, ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_UNDEFINED);
        Matrix matrix = new Matrix();
        switch (orientation) {
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_90:
                matrix.setRotate(90);
                break;
            case ExifInterface.ORIENTATION_ROTATE_180:
                matrix.setRotate(180);
                break;
            default:
        }
        Bitmap rotatedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(bitmap, 0, 0, bitmap.getWidth(), bitmap.getHeight(), matrix, true);
        dnc_image.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);
    }
}
```

The idea was that the image be displayed correctly inside the dnc_image object. However I get the following error:

*FATAL EXCEPTION:*
java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'java.lang.String java.io.File.getAbsolutePath()' on a null object reference

Can someone help me?

Comment: imgFile.getAbsolutePath() - this line seems to produce a null pointer. Are you sure that imgFile is set by the time you call rotateImage()?

Comment: imgFile is being obtained through the database. The table is string type and leads to the file in a folder.

Comment: The best thing to do would be to post your entire class so we can see more scope.

Comment: updated to full code.

Comment: Please see my answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Thanks for updating your code.

This issue you are having is that your `rotateImage` method is hitting the global `imgFile` variable.

Change this line 
`File imgFile = new  File(dnc.getImagem().toString());`

to
`imgFile = new  File(dnc.getImagem().toString());`

This should then solve your null pointer issue. It may be worth you doing some reading on variable scope.

I hope that helps.

Comment: java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method ImageView.setImageBitmap(android.graphics.Bitmap)' on a null object reference. Line code reference: dnc_image.setImageBitmap(rotatedBitmap);

Comment: That is a different issue. That is concerning setting a Bitmap on an ImageView. That should be in another question. If you have got further, it seems my answer was correct.

Comment: Yes your question helped me to move forward, however I can not still displaying the properly rotated image in ImageView = (

Comment: I'm trying to do this: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=mZbL2ofcdP0 But I can not.

Comment: Please any help?